# Error while running the WAMP Server

Tags: php

I receive the following error while running the WAMP Server:

```
php-win.exe- Entry Point not found

PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '../ext/php_intl.dll'- The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Comment: check the operating system 32 bit or 64 bit if you are using window

Comment: Is that dll in the right place ? Did it come bundled with WAMP or did you install it afterwards ? Your question really doesn't provide enough details.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED :
1. Try to reinstall the latest update of Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable..
2. If it is already up to date, check the following link.
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679